# setting affinity with taskset nt work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, affinity

When I want to set an affinity to a process like this:

```
sudo taskset -c 0 -p 30466
```

I get this error:

```
taskset: executing -p failed: No such file or directory
```

However `top` command shows the process is executing.

**UPDATE:**

The command

```
 sudo taskset -c -p 0 30466
```

works

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax is `taskset -cp 0 30466`

Old question but still viewed a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason taskset is trying to execute the command `-p`, and isn't even tried to look for the process with the PID you specify.

Which version of taskset are you using? Can you check with `man taskset` whether your version supports `-p`?